# Restricting certain pages of a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and I want to allow certain page to be viewed by guest or available to be viewed by the public in a controller.

It works like this: Each user can register and create few posts. The home page will show all posts from all users. So the `PostController` will have something like:

```
public function __construct(Post $post, User $user)
 {
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->post = $post;
    $this->user = $user;
 }

public function index()
 {
    $posts =  \Auth::user()->posts;
    return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
 }

public function show($id)
 {
    //return "Post Listing";
    $post = $this->post->where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
 }
```

I could go on and list the `create` function and more but I want the general public to see the `show` function or the show page without the need to register. Is that possible or I have to redesign the application?

The app is setup that once logged in, the user can see their own posts on a separate page. But the home page will show all post regardless if logged in or not.

I could have something like this `$posts = $this->post->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();`to show all posts but that does not work well.

***EDIT****

I need to show the user's name etc with: `$posts =  \Auth::user()->posts;`

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly
you may do so

```
$this->middleware('auth',['except'=>['index','show']]);
```

Comment: Hi. While I see where you are going, you are partially correct in my case. The issue is with `$posts =  \Auth::user()->posts;` That is used to show all posts but I get:  Cannot access property on non-object

Comment: ok, then did you define the posts relationship in your user model ? you need to have that defined before you can invoke ->posts on user model in your index(), you can do `$posts = \Auth::check() ? \Auth::user()->posts : $this->post->get();`